# java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android

Для кэширования использую стороннюю библиотеку DualCache. При создании экземпляра DualCache вылетает следующая ошибка

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/vincentbrison/openlibraries/android/dualcache/lib/DualCache
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Вот ссылка на библиотеку https://github.com/vincentbrison/android-easy-cache/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vincentbrison/openlibraries/android/dualcache/DemoActivity.java

Comment: например, Вы используете скомпилированный jar файл этой библиотеки, который скомпилирован под другую версию jdk.

Comment: вы не привели ни ссылку на библиотеку, ни ее описания. Спросите у автора библиотеки, в чем проблема.

Comment: Добавила ссылку;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `java.lang.VerifyError` возникает, когда виртуальная машина Android'а - Dalvik VM не может найти загрузить объектный код какого-то класса.

Дело в том, что Dalvik VM использует немного другой формат объектных кодов нежели который генерируется для JVM. Есть специальная утилита `dx`, которая конвертит `.class` файлы в сборку `.dex` (которая и есть объектник Dalvik VM).

В вашем случае, почему так получилось причин может быть несколько. Возможно вы просто собрали .jar для JVM и пытаетесь его загрузить или возможно есть проблема с версионностью `dx` (входит в состав Android Build Tools). Возможно есть проблема с `targetSdk` в манифесте.

Посмотрите на свой `build.gradle` и `AndroidManifest.xml`